# Finding the range of cols by row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that houses cols of numbers - id like to check the range between these cols by row and create a new col that contains this range....

```
tool1   tool2   tool3    range
1       34      12       33
na      19      23       4
```

its has to be able to handle NAs too, byt just ignoring them.

How could this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the range between these cols"? Min and max per row? Providing the desired output would improve this question. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Range = max val - min val....I should have said calculate the range into a new column. The desired output is on my example under col Range

Comment: `df$range <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm = T))` or `df$range <- apply(df, 1, function(x) diff(range(x, na.rm = T)))`

Comment: Convert your "na" value in column 1 to a real `NA` value and then use the approach by @DavidArenburg.

Answer (score 2):

I've decide to expand this, because operating on rows in R is always a pain. So I've decided to compare base R against the two very efficient packages `data.table` and `dplyr`
(I'm not a `dplyr` expert, so if someone wants to modify my answer, please do)

Note:
Your case isn't a classic case of operating on rows because it can be solved using vectorized `pmax` and `pmin`, which we won't be always able to use

So creating a bit bigger data than in your example

```
n <- 1e4
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(tool1 = sample(100, n, replace = T),
                 tool2 = sample(100, n, replace = T),
                 tool3 = sample(100, n, replace = T))
```

Loading the necessary packages

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
```

Defining the functions

```
apply1 <- function(y) apply(y, 1, function(x) max(x, na.rm = T) - min(x, na.rm = T)) 
apply2 <- function(y) apply(y, 1, function(x) diff(range(x, na.rm = T)))
trans <- function(y) transform(y, range = pmax(tool1, tool2, tool3) - pmin(tool1, tool2, tool3))
DTfunc <- function(y) setDT(y)[, range := pmax(tool1, tool2, tool3) - pmin(tool1, tool2, tool3)]
DTfunc2 <- function(y) set(y, j = "range", value = with(y, pmax(tool1, tool2, tool3) - pmin(tool1, tool2, tool3))) # Thanks to @Arun for this
dplyrfunc <- function(y) mutate(y, range = pmax(tool1, tool2, tool3) - pmin(tool1, tool2, tool3))

df2 <- as.data.table(df) # This is in order to avoid overriding df by `setDT` during benchmarking
```

Running some benchmarks

```
microbenchmark(apply1(df), apply2(df), trans(df), DTfunc(df2), DTfunc2(df2), dplyrfunc(df), times = 100)
Unit: microseconds
          expr        min          lq      median         uq        max neval
    apply1(df)  37221.513  40699.3790  44103.3495  46777.305  94845.463   100
    apply2(df) 262440.581 278239.6460 287478.4710 297301.116 343962.869   100
     trans(df)   1088.799   1178.3355   1234.9940   1287.503   1965.328   100
   DTfunc(df2)   2068.750   2221.8075   2317.5680   2400.400   5935.883   100
  DTfunc2(df2)    903.981    959.0435    986.3355   1026.395   1235.951   100
 dplyrfunc(df)   1040.280   1118.9635   1159.9815   1200.680   1509.189   100
```

Seems like the second `data.table` approach is the most efficient. Base R `transform` and `dplyr` both pretty much the same, while more efficient than the first `data.table` approach because of the overhead in calling `[.data.table`

Comment: nice benchmark! you can slightly optimize the `dplyr` speed by using `mutate(df, range = pmax(tool1, tool2, tool3) - pmin(tool1, tool2, tool3))`

Comment: +1 for the options. I wonder how `matrixStats` (which gives us `rowMaxs` and so on) compares.... My guess is that it would be faster than `apply`, but still slower than the other options.

Comment: @ananda, wheres the +1? ;)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, doh! I haven't had my coffee yet :-)